# What is the scope of the drupal session cookie?

Tags: 7, cookies, bootstrapping

I am bootstrapping drupal 7 (using DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL) so that I can use drupal's authentication/security features in the rapid development of a web app I'm doing a proof of concept for. (And yes I know it is better to use drush to bootstrap drupal.)

If the PHP file that I am bootstrapping drupal from is in the root drupal directory, then the bootstrapping works -- I know this because inspecting the $user global variable will show that I am logged in.

If the PHP file is not in the root drupal directory (whether a subdirectory of the root drupal directory or a sibling of the root drupal directory), then the bootstrapping works -- I can inspect the $user global variable, but the $user variable says I am an anonymous user rather than the logged in user that I am.

Is my suspicion right that this is related to the scope of the drupal session cookie? If so, what is that scope?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never?

Yes, if you are creating the cookie with a default path. It will use the current page path. So the cookie will be restricted to any path starting with the defined one (if it's /a/b then the cookie will be available for /a/b, a/b/c etc but not /a alone).

(I had a short period of hair-tearing once where I was accessing a site using it's IP address and unable to understand why the cookies weren't available ... they were hardwired to the domain.)